# Unable to successfully un-minimize window in SDL 2.x

Tags: events, window, sdl

Currently, my program is losing focus and not processing after minimizing and unminimizing(restore/re-expose) of window.

I've added debugging code to my code to search out what is happening after you restore the window post-hitting minimize.

The Event that seems to be occurring is `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`.

After, the window is re-expose I attempt to process it; but nothing happens. The window is unresponsive until I hit restore down.

Here is my code:

```
void GPE_Renderer::handle_events(SDL_Event& e)
{
     //Window event occured
    if( e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT )
    {
        //Caption update flag
        switch( e.window.event )
        {
            //Get new dimensions and repaint on window size change
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED:
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
                if( isMinimized)
                {
                    SDL_RestoreWindow(gpeWindow);
                    //SDL_SetWindowSize(gpeWindow,mWidth,mHeight);
                    rWidth = mWidth;
                    rHeight = mHeight;
                    isMinimized = false;
                    clear_renderer();
                    record_error("Window unminimized");
                }
                else
                {
                    if( e.window.data1>0 && e.window.data2 > 0)
                    {
                        mWidth = rWidth = e.window.data1;
                        mHeight = rHeight = e.window.data2;
                        isMinimized = false;
                        record_error("Window reiszed with proper data");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rWidth = mWidth;
                        rHeight = mHeight;
                        record_error("Window resize with improper data");
                    }
                }
                WINDOW_WAS_JUST_RESIZED = true;
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED:
                isMinimized = true;
                isResized = true;
                mWidth = rWidth;
                mHeight = rHeight;
                WINDOW_WAS_JUST_RESIZED = true;
                record_error("Window minimized");
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ENTER:

            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED:
                if( isMinimized)
                {
                    isMinimized = false;
                    WINDOW_WAS_JUST_RESIZED = true;
                    SDL_SetWindowSize(gpeWindow,mWidth,mHeight);
                    SCREEN_WIDTH =  rWidth = mWidth;
                    SCREEN_HEIGHT = rHeight = mHeight;
                    clear_renderer();
                    record_error("Window unminimized from being exposed!");
                 }
                else
                {
                    record_error("Window exposed!!!!");
                }
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_LEAVE:
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED:
                SDL_SetWindowTitle(gpeWindow,"[Game Pencil Engine]");
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST:
                SDL_SetWindowTitle(gpeWindow,"*Out of Focus*Game Pencil Engine");
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE:
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESTORED:
                if( isMinimized)
                {
                    //SDL_SetWindowSize(gpeWindow,mWidth,mHeight);
                    rWidth = mWidth;
                    rHeight = mHeight;
                    isMinimized = false;
                    record_error("Window restored and unminimized");
                }
                else
                {
                    rWidth = mWidth = MIN_WINDOW_WIDTH;
                    rHeight = mHeight = MIN_WINDOW_HEIGHT;
                    record_error("Window restored.");
                }
                isResized = true;
                WINDOW_WAS_JUST_RESIZED = true;
            break;
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_NONE:
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the window has to be restored manually at this point(and maximized for normal effect).

Here is what I added in the `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` case after checking if the screen was minimized:

I fixed it.

Apparently I have to restore the window.

I added these lines in the expose event (after checking on minimize) and this works:

```
SDL_RestoreWindow(gpeWindow);
SDL_MaximizeWindow(gpeWindow);
SDL_GetWindowSize(gpeWindow,&mWidth,&mHeight);
```